# Iterate through SignalR clients

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm pretty new to SignalR. I tried to look for a solution but with no success.
Is there a way to iterate through the Clients in SignalR?
That is, I need to check each client state and decide what to do according to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is an easier way. But the way I implemented it is by creating a static list and each time a user connects I add them  to that list. And remove the user on disconnect.